# Hide (Or Filter) some Columns of Columns Group

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using a Report Builder 3 Matrix and specifying Row Groups and Column Groups. Basically its a master detail type situation, where in my case the Entities are Relays and Contacts. Each relay has multiple contacts. A few important properties of both are given below.

**Relay:**
Name (simple field),
 
Type (Enum Field),
Contacts (navigation field to Contacts Entity. One to Many)

**Contacts:**
DisplayName (simple field)
AllotedToSheet (simple field).

Here is how the report looks like. The Columns are generated from "Display Name" field of **Contacts** table using Column Groupings.

[image: Generated Report Sample]

Now here is the issue. I have marked 2 regions in the Report above. That is the case because I have two types of Relays (say for now). The "Display Name" fields of Contacts table are same for a particular relay type, so I get two sets of columns (as marked) in my report. Based on the Relay Type, I want to Generate or Show only one set of columns for the entire report because the other set does not make sense for Relay Type and Each Relay Type will have its own generated report (rdl). So how do I achieve this.

In summary, for columns generated using Column Groups, how to I filter out or hide certain columns from the report based on some database field.value condition

**Edit: Report Designer View**
[image]

Comment: I have a few questions. What is your SQL as these columns shouldn't come through if you don't want them to? Also is this report only for one relay type?

Comment: The SQL query that is generated just have JOIN for columns of related tables. I added a WHERE clause in the DATASET query for the Relay_Type and now only the relevant columns are generated. So now, I don't have to add the visibility expression for hiding some columns. Anyways, Visibility for generated columns doesn't hide the column but turn's it into empty white space for the column, so not of any use to me. I came accross a couple of blogs where I could confirm this. So you are absolutely correct about your comment that this should be handled in SQL itself. I will mark your comment as useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @glh's suggestion to modify the DataSet Query directly, I was able to generate only the records (in my case columns) that were relevant to a particular Relay_Type. In the Query, I just had to add a SQL **WHERE** clause which would load details records of only a particular Relay_Type. This way the only columns that were relevant for a particular Relay_Type were generated by the Query in the DataSet. So there was no need to change the visibility expression to hide the Columns. In fact, Visibility expression didn't hide the columns, it just "Blanked it Out" taking space in the report. So modifying SQL seems to be better option for my case.

Nirvan.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the **Column Visibility** to be expression based?

[image]

[image]

Set the expression to something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!RelayType.Value = "Relay1", false, true)
```

Updating as required for different relay/column combinations.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that would be possible. The Columns are generated dynamically based on "Column Groups" and I don't have individual access to those generated column in report design. If you see the image that I have posted in my question, the first three columns are the only ones which I can really set the properties like visibility. All the columns beyond "Relays_Name" column are generated dynamically based on the Contacts table data.

Comment: Please see the designer view image that I have added in the original question above. That will make my question more clear.

Comment: @Nirvan It's been a while since I've worked with dynamic columns, but I think it doesn't matter if they are dynamically created. You have one column on your report builder, just apply Ian's solution to that one and it will be valid for all columns in that group. Did you test?

Comment: Yes, I actually didn't think that I could just apply them for the group either as filter or as visibility. Good point, I will give it a try.

Comment: @eestein, I tried the visibility expression, but instead of hiding the column altogether, the reporting services, just inserts white space for the matching the column values. The Report Headers still appear. If its not clear from this comment, I can post the new  generated report image, just let me know.

Comment: @Nirvan ok, I'll see if I can try something here.

Comment: @eestein, Actually, I have solved the issue by modifying the generating SQL query directly based on the suggestion from glh. I just had to add a WHERE clause in SQL query to get records only for a particular Relay_Type. That way the DataSet is only populated with the records of particular Relay_Type. Thanks for the favor though.

Comment: @Nirvan ok, no problem, just add your solution and mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best you link the tables via a join in the SQL. This will remove the extra columns being populated in the dataset.

Comment: Yes, I think writing the SQL instead of having it generated might be a good call. I actually had some IBM MAINFRAME experience where we used raw SQL a lot and I still have hangovers of it. But, now in this Object era I doubt whether developers have a strong foundation of SQL. So its not much of a option for some though. Thanks

Comment: Understood, the added benifit for doing this in the sql is performance as the report would have to retrieve all the data, then cut some out, them display it for you and hide columns as required.